# Apply a binary function to two Pandas Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series

What is the recommended way to apply a [binary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_function) to two [Pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) elementwise, pairing values together when they have the same index, and providing a fill value when one of the series is missing a value?

For example, input series `sl` and `sr` should produce output series `so`:

```
sl = Pandas Series
index,value
a,1
b,4
c,5
e,7

sr = Pandas Series
index,value
a,2
b,3
d,6
e,7

so = binary_func(sl, sr, fill_value=0)
index,value
a,binary_func(1,2)
b,binary_func(4,3)
c,binary_func(5,0)
d,binary_func(0,6)
e,binary_func(7,7)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DataFrame with [**`fillna(0)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and then [**`apply`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) your `binary_func` on the rows:

```py
import pandas as pd

sl = pd.Series([1, 4, 5, 7], index=list('abce'))
sr = pd.Series([2, 3, 6, 7], index=list('abde'))

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'sl': sl, 'sr': sr }).fillna(0)
```

|  | sl | sr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1.0 | 2.0 |
| b | 4.0 | 3.0 |
| c | 5.0 | 0.0 |
| d | 0.0 | 6.0 |
| e | 7.0 | 7.0 |

```py
so = df.apply(lambda row: binary_func(row[0], row[1]), axis=1)
```

Comment: This is actually running really slowly for me though (on a large data set).  I wonder if there is a more efficient solution.  Still a nice answer though.

Comment: Instead of the `df.apply` step, try vectorizing the function like `binary_func_vec = np.vectorize(binary_func)`

and then calling it with the numpy arrays like `binary_func_vec(df.s1.values, df.s2.values)`.

Comment: Thanks!  If that works it would deserve to be a separate answer.  A speed comparison between the two approaches would be valuable!